# Verilog - Is it possible to assign values to a register based on the genvar variables in a generate block

Tags: for-loop, verilog, assign, synthesis

I have some code similar to this (one below is an example):

```
genvar x;
genvar y;
generate
    for (y = -off; y < off; y=y+1) begin
        for (x = -off; x < off; x=x+1) begin
            guassian_kernel[((((y+off)*ks)+x+off+1)*fs)-1:(((y+off)*ks)+x+off)] = x*y; // <- something like this
        end
    end
endgenerate
```

Is it possible to do something like that or like:

```
20'd(x*y)
```

etc?

Or do I have no other choice except to hardcode all the register values? In the actual code I'm using, the values in the reg would be a much more complicated function of x and y.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

a `generate` block only used to **generate** regular verilog statements, like module instantiations, always blocks, assign statements, ... It is kind of pre-processing.

So, your assignment must be a legal verilog statement, e.g.,

```
generate
for (y = -off; y < off; y=y+1) begin
    for (x = -off; x < off; x=x+1) begin
        always @*  // <-- something like this.
             guassian_kernel[((((y+off)*ks)+x+off+1)*fs)-1:(((y+off)*ks)+x+off)] = x*y; 
    end
end
endgenerate
```